# google calenderID nodejs doesn't work with specified CalendarID

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I would like to use a google calendar, if I choose the calendar ID not as primary but with the specified one, I get an error message in `line 46 (const eventsArray = res.data.calendars.calID.busy)`. The Error message looks like this `(node:49993) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'calendar' of undefined`. So basicly, i believe, it can't read the calender ID, can enyone help me to find my fault?

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
    const { OAuth2 } = google.auth;
    const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2(
        'id_works_with_primary_calender', 
        'key_works_with_primary_calender'
    )
    
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
        refresh_token: 
            'works_with_primary',
    })
    
    const calendar = google.calendar( { version: 'v3', auth: oAuth2Client } );
    
    const eventStartTime = new Date()
    eventStartTime.setDate(eventStartTime.getDay() + 2)
    
    const eventEndTime = new Date()
    eventEndTime.setDate(eventEndTime.getDay() + 2)
    eventEndTime.setMinutes(eventEndTime.getMinutes() + 45)
    
    const event = {
        summary: 'Meet with David',
        location: '295 California St, San Francisco, CA 94111',
        description: 'Meeting with David to talk about the new client Project and drink some stuff',
        colorId: 1,
        start: {
            dateTime: eventStartTime,
            timeZone: 'Europe/Zurich',
        },
        end: {
            dateTime: eventEndTime,
            timeZone: 'Europe/Zurich',
        },
    }
    
    calendar.freebusy.query( {
        resource: {
            timeMin: eventStartTime,
            timeMax: eventEndTime,
            timeZone: 'Europe/Zurich',
        items: [ { id: 'gd3q30fhkprf0ubsk3pnqkc64k@group.calendar.google.com' } ],
        },
    }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) return console.error('Free Busy Query Error: ', err)
        //Here is the error    
        const eventsArray = res.data.calendars.gd3q30fhkprf0ubsk3pnqkc64k@group.calendar.google.com.busy
        if(eventsArray.length === 0)
            return calendar.events.insert( { 
                calendarId: 'gd3q30fhkprf0ubsk3pnqkc64k@group.calendar.google.com',
                resource: event,
            },
            err => {
                if (err) return console.error('Calender Event Creation: ' + err)
                    return console.log('Event Created: ' + event)    
        })
        return console.log("I'm Busy")
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

The problem seems to be that the `id` includes several dots, and the program thinks these are used to access nested properties. Because of this, it is looking for the property `calendar` of the id `gd3q30fhkprf0ubsk3pnqkc64k@group` and, of course, it's not finding it, because the correct id is `gd3q30fhkprf0ubsk3pnqkc64k@group.calendar.google.com`.

#### Solution:

Therefore, assuming that this `id` is getting returned by `res.data.calendars`, the problem should be solved by changing the syntax with which you are accessing the `key` property, from dot notation to bracket notation.

That is to say, replace this:

```
const eventsArray = res.data.calendars.gd3q30fhkprf0ubsk3pnqkc64k@group.calendar.google.com.busy
```

With this:

```
const eventsArray = res.data.calendars["gd3q30fhkprf0ubsk3pnqkc64k@group.calendar.google.com"].busy
```

#### Reference:

- [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)